# Using xlrd to read selected columns and all rows in python

Tags: python, excel, arcpy

I would like to loop through an excel table and get the values for selected columns in each row in a set of lists or dictionary.  if in a dictionary, for each row, the value in the first selected column would be the key and the values in the other selected columns would be the values (array) for that key.  I cannot figure out how to tell python to read values from only selected columns...for the excel table may have 10 columns but I am only interest in three for example, and the three of interest are not contiguous.  Would appreciate your insights using XLRD.

```
    import xlrd
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    import arcpy

    wb = open_workbook ("c:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Marion\\Courses\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\Data\\ExcelFiles\\Belize_Culvert_Nov15_V4.0.xlsx")

    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

    keys = [sheet.cell(0, 5).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]

    dict_list = []
    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
        d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(0, 5).value 
        for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}:
            dict_list.append(d)
```

The field that I want to use as key is column 5 and the values are columns #16 and #17 as an array value for each key...

Comment: import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import arcpy

wb = open_workbook ("c:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Marion\\Courses\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\Data\\ExcelFiles\\Belize_Culvert_Nov15_V4.0.xlsx")
print wb.nsheets
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

keys = [sheet.cell(0, 5).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]

dict_list = []
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
         for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
    dict_list.append(d)

print dict_list

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code, and state **what worked, and what didn't**.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command

```
row_slice(rowx, start_colx=0, end_colx=None)
```

Returns a slice of the Cell objects in the given row.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in your code -

1. `keys = [sheet.cell(0, 5).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]` - This always takes the keys as the value in the first row and 6th column  (Rows and columns are 0 indexed.)
2. `d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(0, 5).value` - This is not even valid python syntax

You can just loop over all the rows, take column index 4 (5th column) as key and the rest in a list and add that to a dictionary, Example -

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import arcpy

wb = open_workbook ("c:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Marion\\Courses\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\Data\\ExcelFiles\\Belize_Culvert_Nov15_V4.0.xlsx")

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
sheetdict = {}
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum,4)] = [sheet.cell(rownum,15),sheet.cell(rownum,16)]
```

In the end, `sheetdict` has the required dictionary.